# luwit form navigation

Tags: navigation, lwuit, codenameone

Suppose that I have 3 form "Main", "Setting", "Language". I start with "Main" and then I open "Setting" from "Main" and after that open "Language" from "Setting" ("Main" -> "Setting" -> "Language").

How can I implement navigation between these forms?

codenameone and lwuit do it by set nextform property but I want to implement it manually but I don't know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Codename One state machine just invoke `showForm("FormName", null);` to show any form you want whenever you want. Just make sure to call it from the EDT.

Comment: Thanks Shai. As the matter of fact I implement them by hard choding and all of my classes derive from "com.codenameone.ui.form" class. So I wanna implemenet navigation manually. Is there any solution to do it manually?

Comment: Next form is a feature of the GUI builder and has no code equivalent. What's the problem with just showing a form when you want to if you are in code already?

Comment: I didn't use GUI builder for design so all of my forms are derived by Form not UIBuiler. Therefor I wanna Implement my own Next Form and I did. But I wanna some solution to benchmark of Next Form implementation.